# change max-height by clicking collapse button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Have the following puzzle: there are two tables on the page and a button. the table1 is shown at once and table2 is shown with the help of button toggle. The idea is that clicking the button causes not only expanding of table2 but should change the max-height of table1 (when table2 is expanded, table 1 becomes smaller and when table2 is not show, table1 is big ). I use knockout and its click doesn't work with bootstrap data-toggle="collapse" that is why the solution is done by

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: showAllEvents ">events</button>

this.showAllEvents = function () {
  //things to do
   $("#table2").toggle(); // show and hide table2
   };
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not _entirely_ clear on what you're asking here, but have you seen [Knockstrap](http://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/)?  Helps to bridge the gap between knockout and bootstrap

Comment: Don't do DOM manipulations outside of binding handlers. Knockstrap may give you what you want. If not, you'll need to write custom binding handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this to toggle the tables - [codepen](http://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/eNWLEM)

The important bits -

html

```
<div class="table-container" data-bind="css: { expanded: expandTable}">
```

js

```
//Viewmodel
mynamespace.TableThing = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.expandTable= ko.observable(true);
  self.toggle = function(){
    if(self.expandTable()){
      self.expandTable(false)
    }else{
      self.expandTable(true)
    }
  }
};
```

css

```
.table-container{
  height:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.table-container.expanded{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your code, the only thing is that the table1 should become smaller (should not be hidden completely). But i think css bind the right way out.

Comment: table1 doesn't become hidden, just smaller - here is a less dramatic hiding - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqmVGj